# R studio: Linear regression, elasticity and hypothesis testing

Tags: statistics

I'm having some trouble with solving an empirical example for a linear regression with the help of R studio as I only have very basic knowledge of R Studio.

I'm supposed to use the data set ’wage2’ from the R package “wooldridge”.
The linear regression model (LRM) is lwage = β_1 + β_2 ·educ + β_3 · exper +ε

For the estimation of the linear regression model I did the following in R:

model1 <- lm(formula = log(wage) ~ educ + exper, data = lwage)

summary(model1)

After that the I'm supposed to *extend the LRM to allow the effect of educ to depend on the level of work experience and estimate the new model by OLS. Let θ be the semielasticity of wage w.r.t. education after 10 years of work experience. Estimate θ and test whether it is significantly different from zero at the 1% significance level.*

*Afterwards state the null hypothesis that the return to education does not depend on the level of experience.*

I get the first step as: model2 <- lm(formula= log(wage) ~ educ + exper + educ*exper, data = lwage)

summary(model2)

But afterwards I don't know how to continue and how I calculate the semi-elasticity with R...

I started with: theta <- formula$Coefficients["educ"]*mean(lwage[,2])/mean(lwage[,6])*mean(lwage[exper = "10"]) but I get an error and I'm not sure if the formula is correct.

Thanks in advance for your help. I appreciate it a lot

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: Try https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thx. I'll do that